# Programmatically authenticate user in TAI

Tags: java, websphere, websphere-portal, websphere-6.1

I'm developing `TAI` which have to authorize user in WebSphere Portal.

My `TAI` using `OpenID` Connect gets all information about user and i want to build some context, give it to WAS and tell WAS that he has to trust for this context without local account.

How i can auth user in `TAI` without user account in local repositories?

UPDATE:

Code:

```
String userid = "bob";
String uniqueid = "bob";

Hashtable hashtable = new Hashtable();
hashtable.put(AttributeNameConstants.WSCREDENTIAL_UNIQUEID, uniqueid);
hashtable.put(AttributeNameConstants.WSCREDENTIAL_SECURITYNAME, userid);
hashtable.put(AttributeNameConstants.WSCREDENTIAL_CACHE_KEY, uniqueid+"MyCustom");

Subject subject = new Subject();
subject.getPublicCredentials().add(hashtable);
return TAIResult.create(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK, "ignored", subject);
```

Log:

```
[25.03.15 20:16:33:521 AMT] 00000043 ServiceLogger I com.ibm.ws.ffdc.IncidentStreamImpl initialize FFDC0009I: FFDC opened incident stream file  WebSphere_Portal_00000043_15.03.25_20.16.33_0.txt
[25.03.15 20:16:33:537 AMT] 00000043 ServiceLogger I com.ibm.ws.ffdc.IncidentStreamImpl resetIncidentStream FFDC0010I: FFDC closed incident stream file WebSphere_Portal_00000043_15.03.25_20.16.33_0.txt
[25.03.15 20:16:33:677 AMT] 00000043 StorageApi    E com.ibm.wps.policy.commands.StorageApi StorageApi EJQAB0064E: A Null argument was passed to the StorageApi constructor.
[25.03.15 20:16:33:724 AMT] 00000043 PolicyService E com.ibm.wps.policy.services.PolicyService Error Occured while creating storageAPI EJQAB0064E: A Null argument was passed to the StorageApi constructor.
```

FFDC:

```
------Start of DE processing------ = [3/25/15 20:16:33:474 AMT] , key = com.ibm.websphere.wim.exception.PropertyNotDefinedException com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs 4153
Exception = com.ibm.websphere.wim.exception.PropertyNotDefinedException
Source = com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs
probeid = 4153
Stack Dump = com.ibm.websphere.wim.exception.PropertyNotDefinedException: CWWIM0514W The 'dn' property is not defined.
```

For this error i found [this information](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS7K4U_6.1.0/com.ibm.websphere.wim.doc.en/messages25.html?cp=SS7K4U_6.1.0%2F1-7-9-9-1-1-0-4-26-6-5-21).

But i don't understand they want me do...

Description:

I have FederatedRepositories where only one LDAP repository.

UPDATE #2:

I made such TAI on WAS 8.5.5.2 and there no errors, just white screen. I tried auth user "bob" with group "wpsadmins". There are FederatedRepositories with one file-based built-in repository.

UPDATE #3:

I wrote custom application for WAS where i have a button, which make POST request to Servlet.

Partially code:

```
if (req.getRemoteUser() == null) {
    req
            .setAttribute("errorMessage",
                    "<b>Error: Please log in before accessing PrintUserInfo.<b>");
    RequestDispatcher disp = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(
            "/login.jsp");
    disp.forward(req, resp);
    return;
}
resp.setContentType("text/html");
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(resp.getOutputStream());

String id = WSSubject.getCallerPrincipal();
out.println("The WAS Subject layer thinks you are " + id);
    Context ic = new InitialContext();
    Object objRef = ic.lookup("UserRegistry");
    UserRegistry userReg = (UserRegistry) PortableRemoteObject.narrow(
            objRef, UserRegistry.class);
    out.println("<BR><BR>The user registry says your display name is: "
            + userReg.getUserDisplayName(req.getUserPrincipal()
                    .getName()));

    Subject subject = WSSubject.getCallerSubject();
    Set credSet = subject.getPublicCredentials(WSCredential.class);
    //should be impossible.
    if (credSet.size() > 1) {
        System.out
                .println("Expected only one WSCredential in Subject set");
        throw new Exception("Expected one WSCredential, found "
                + credSet.size());
    }
if (credSet.isEmpty()) {
    System.out.println("Credential set is empty");
    throw new Exception("Found no credentials");
}
//get one and only one element of Set
Iterator iter = credSet.iterator();
WSCredential creds = (WSCredential) iter.next();
out.println("<BR><BR>Looking into your Subject your userid is "
        + creds.getSecurityName());
out.println("<BR><BR>Looking into your Subject your uniqueid is "
        + creds.getUniqueSecurityName());
out
        .println("<BR><BR>Looking into your Subject I see these groups: ");
//List groups = helper.getGroups();
List groups = creds.getGroupIds();
iter = groups.iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    String gid = (String) iter.next();
    out.println("<BR>Group ID: " + gid);
}
```

New version of TAI:

```
String userid = "alisa";
String uniqueid = "bob";

// add admin group 

// stash in hashtable
Hashtable hashtable = new Hashtable();


try {
    InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
    UserRegistry reg  =(UserRegistry)ctx.lookup("UserRegistry");
    String wpsadminsGroupUniqueId = reg.getUniqueGroupId("wpsadmins");
    List<String> groups = new ArrayList<String>();
    groups.add(wpsadminsGroupUniqueId);
    hashtable.put(AttributeNameConstants.WSCREDENTIAL_GROUPS, groups);
} catch (Exception  e) {
    System.out.println("EXCEPTION IN TAI");
    e.printStackTrace();
}

hashtable.put(AttributeNameConstants.WSCREDENTIAL_UNIQUEID,uniqueid);
hashtable.put(AttributeNameConstants.WSCREDENTIAL_SECURITYNAME,userid);
hashtable.put(AttributeNameConstants.WSCREDENTIAL_CACHE_KEY,uniqueid+"MyCustom");

Subject subject = new Subject();
subject.getPublicCredentials().add(hashtable);
return TAIResult.create(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK, "ignored", subject);
```

So i got from Subject i get my credentials, includes userId, uniqueId and groups from LDAP.

Result:

```
The WAS Subject layer thinks you are alisa 

The user registry says your display name is: 

Looking into your Subject your userid is alisa 

Looking into your Subject your uniqueid is bob 

Looking into your Subject I see these groups: 
Group ID: group:domain:port/cn=wpsadmins,cn=CN,ou=OU,o=O,o=O,c=ru
```

UPDATE #4

I added in TAI a few groups and than i authorize in Portal (i think), but i see only white screen without anything. What's wrong?

UPDATE #5

And WPS gives me an exception:

```
[26.03.15 18:47:41:006 AMT] 0000004e DefaultLoginF E com.ibm.wps.auth.impl.DefaultLoginFilter doLoginWithExceptions WpsException occured: com.ibm.wps.services.authentication.exceptions.UserRetrieveException: EJPSD0008E: Exception occurred while retrieving the user [null] from the user registry.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create full subject, for more details check [Advanced authentication in WebSphere Application Server](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/0508_benantar/0508_benantar.html).

In short you need to use similar code:

```
String userid = "bob";//get from request
String uniqueid = "bob";

// stash in hashtable
Hashtable hashtable = new Hashtable();
hashtable.put(AttributeNameConstants.WSCREDENTIAL_UNIQUEID,uniqueid);
hashtable.put(AttributeNameConstants.WSCREDENTIAL_SECURITYNAME,userid);
// hashtable.put(AttributeNameConstants.WSCREDENTIAL_GROUPS,groups);
hashtable.put(AttributeNameConstants.WSCREDENTIAL_CACHE_KEY,uniqueid+"MyCustom");

Subject subject = new Subject();
subject.getPublicCredentials().add(hashtable);
return TAIResult.create(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK, "ignored", subject);
```

Comment: This code require uniqueId. But this uniqueId retrieved from UserRegistry by userId. So i have no user account in UserRegistry i wont retrieve uniqueId.

Comment: @dikkini  No, you can set this user Id by yourself in the correct format without getting it from registry, check this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27721289/3701228) where I create and use user not existing in the repository. This user will be treated as authenticated, but it will be hard to map it to something different that all authenticated, if you will not get groups from repository.

Comment: Stack Dump = com.ibm.websphere.wim.exception.InvalidUniqueNameException: CWWIM1011E The 'test' unique name is not valid.

Comment: I think, trouble because i have only LDAP repository of users. And i have to make Federated Repository. But i don't know which repository type i need with LDAP in Federated Repo.

Comment: @dikkini I'm on Federated repo with only file registry, I dont have user `bob` there and above code just works. So add your TAI code with the subject creation to the question and describe, when you are getting that error (stacktrace). You should not call user registry with your dummy username.

Comment: @dikkini So as you can see your user IS authenticated. Its hard to tell what is your current problem.

Comment: where did you see that user is authenticated? My problem because i use in FederatedRepositories LDAP repository, not file based

Comment: @dikkini You would have unauthenticated exception. I've tested it also with Federated w LDAP. Works exactly the same. It might be related to Portal so you should test it on simple application like snoop servlet. Registry actually doesnt matter as if you provide all the details, registry is not queried at all. Writing TAI is not easy, thats why I suggested you in other thread to use provided one.

Comment: I wrote my custom application for test purpose. I will update my question now, take a look please.

Comment: tell me please, can i redirect user to specific page after successfully authentificate (return TAIResult.create(SC_OK, "userId"))?

Comment: @dikkini - I've never tried that, but there is `WASReqURL` cookie, which tells the server where to redirect user after successful authentication in case of form login. You could try to see, if you will find it during TAI authentication and override value stored there. I cannot guarantee that it will work, but worth a try. Let me know, if it works.

Answer (score 0):

On the WPS Exception added in Update #5
WebSphere Portal requires the uniqueid to be a full qualified DN. In you case you only have a shortname. Portal does lookup the user at VMM using the DN and expects the WSCredential.getUniqueSecurityName() to return a DN.